# TypeError: crypto__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.generateKeyPairSync is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, encryption, cryptojs

I have Node.js v12.13.0 installed but still, I am getting below error. I have checked lots of questions regarding this but solution in all the question is updated node version.

```
Uncaught TypeError: crypto__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.generateKeyPairSync is not a function
    at Login.render (Login.jsx:31)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17098)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17051)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18513)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:189)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:238)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:291)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23055)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22022)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:21995)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21613)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21045)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:24194)
    at react-dom.development.js:24577
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:21763)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:24576)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:24659)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:27)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Object.1 (PlayerStore.jsx:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Comment: No answer on this one?

Comment: Meanwhile the question got answered. Thank you for trying to come up with a solution!

Answer (score 7):

Judging by the stacktrace, it looks like this code is running in the browser. The [`crypto.generateKeyPairSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypairsync_type_options) API is only available in Node.js. Basically, it can only be used server-side, not in the frontend.

You would need something like the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API), built into modern browsers. [Here is an example RSA key pair generation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey#rsa_key_pair_generation)

```js
let keyPair = window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
  {
    name: "RSA-OAEP",
    modulusLength: 4096,
    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
    hash: "SHA-256"
  },
  true,
  ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
);
```

Comment: Nice answer. How did you found out that `crypto.generateKeyPairSync` API is only available in Node.js? (meaning that it can only be used server-side)

Comment: Generally, concepts you find [here (Node.js Docs)](https://nodejs.org/api/documentation.html) and not [here (MDN Web Docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) are specific to running in Node. It can be confusing.

Comment: I see. Good to know. 